# Is there a way to get my wife's iPhone to go on silent automatically during the time?

Tags: iphone, ios

My wife puts her phone on silent at around 10pm as the games notifications disturb sleeping children, she keeps forgetting to put it back in the morning.
Is there an automated way to put the phone on silent during the period between 10pm-7am?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try using [Do Not Disturb](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT204321) (`Settings->Do Not Disturb`) feature on the iPhone. It allows scheduling as well.